# Configure the network interface to send frames with 802.3 format on freebsd

Tags: linux, freebsd, ethernet

Is it possible to configure my Freebsd (or Linux) so that all frames are sent in the 802.3 frame format (with the LLC part of 802.2) rather than Ethernet 2 frame format ?

Thank you